# How to redirect standard output to a file in Elisp using EMACS

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I use with-output-to-temp-buffer function, redirect the standard output to it, save it to a file, switch back to previous buffer, then kill the temp buffer.

```
(require 'find-lisp)
(with-output-to-temp-buffer "*my output*" 
  (mapc 'print (find-lisp-find-files "~/project/clisp" "\\.lisp$"))
  (setq prev-buffer (buffer-name))
  (switch-to-buffer "*my output*")
  (write-region nil nil "test")
  (switch-to-buffer prev-buffer)
  (kill-buffer "*my output*")
  )
```

But error below occur. I don't know why.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Selecting deleted buffer")
```

PS: Is there more elegant way to achieve this in elsip(redirect standard output to a file). Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error occurs because `with-output-to-temp-buffer` tries to display the buffer after evaluating its body, but at that point you have already deleted the buffer.  I think `with-temp-file` is the macro you're looking for.  Its docstring says:

> `(with-temp-file FILE &rest BODY)`
>
> Create a new buffer, evaluate BODY there, and write the buffer to FILE.

You can then bind `standard-output` to the new buffer, something like:

```
(with-temp-file "test.txt"
  (let ((standard-output (current-buffer)))
    (mapc 'print (find-lisp-find-files "~/project/clisp" "\\.lisp$"))))
```

Comment: LouXiu: See also `C-h f with-output-to-temp-buffer RET` for further clarification about that error.